# Cucumber: Multiple Feature Backgrounds Or Equivalent Solution

Tags: java, cucumber

I have multiple environments on which I need to perform some tests.

Each environment has its own set of urls and credentials to log in.

Ideally I needed a tagged Background to log in to the environment under test before each scenario.

E.g.: 
 
@reconnect @dev 
 
    Background: login with username and password
 
        Given user logs on "DEV" homepage with user "XW" and pass "PO"
 
        Then user is displayed home page

@reconnect @prd 
 
    Background: login with username and password
 
        Given user logs on "PRD" homepage with user "XY" and pass "PR"
 
        Then user is displayed home page

Since this option is not available, I tried to use tagged hooks and scenarios, but all matching tags on the scenarios trigger multiple log-ins before each scenario. Example:

@reconnect @dev @prd 
Scenario: aaa

Will run log-ins for both DEV and PRD environments.

Is there any simple and neat way to achieve such an objective without 'SRY'?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple environments? Why are you not creating the user before you login with them? If you did that your tests would run fine in any environment.

Comment: @diabolist The project which I am testing has multiple environments for testing purposes, and I don't have permissions to create users. cheers.

Comment: Then I'd use the environment and configure Cucumber when you run the features so you end up with something like `cucumber features TENV=PRD` and then have 'Given I am a user' set up the credentials based on TENV

Comment: OK. Fair enough. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

One approach that I have seen being implemented at most places is to keep environment details in properties file, instead of keeping it in Cucumber feature files.

You can have either one property file with parameters like dev.url, prd.url etc, or 2 separate files (one for each environment).

When you run the script, you can pass the environment parameter either through maven or jenkins, and then your scripts can pick up correct data based on the environment parameter.

Comment: Cheers. I did something along the lines of this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cukes/YQWlU23u-D4